# Ubuntu Sophos Auto Update

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, sophos

When I use a standard use account will Sophos update properly? It should auto update every hour by itself but when I use a standard use account will everything work properly on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the updater is started in the background, by `savd` so is not affected by what logged in users there are on the system.

savd runs as a daemon started by your OS's init system (normally systemd).
It runs in the background as root.

So when it wants to start an update it is already root. When you run savupdate manually you need to become root (using sudo) before you can successfully run it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I updated Sophos manually I always need to run sudo in the terminal. That is why I ask if there could be a problem with standard use account. When updating automatically will Sophos not be restricted by a standard user permissions and not be able to update components requiring sudo? I mean why is sudo command then required when updating manually.